# Jquery form submit() to the action in the controller then returns an object to the client and not reload page

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want after I call the submit() function in jQuery. It will go to action to process the logic, then the action will return an object to the client, so the client displays it.

I tried many ways but no, please help me.

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/Mycontroller/Save" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
</form> 
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="Save()">Save</button>
```

I want to try Code Js:

```
function Save(
  $("#myform").submit(function (eventData, handler) {
    var resultFromAction = ???
    // I would like to get the object from the action returned
  });
)
```

Or

```
function Save(
  var resultFromAction =  $("#myform").submit(); 
  // I would like to get the object from the action returned
)
```

Code action in controller:

```
public class MyControllerController: Controller {
  [Authorize]
  public ActionResult Save(FormObject formobj) {
    // do something
    var resultForClient = new {
      phone: "098989878",
      name: "john",
      add: "My address"
    };
    return Json(resultForClient, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that my button has a `type="button"` NOT `type= "submit"` and is outside the `form` tag, there is an `onclick="Save()"` event.

Comment: help me, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you should place the `<button>` within the `<form>` and change its `type` to `submit`:

```html
<form action="/Mycontroller/Save" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  First name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br />

  Last name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br /><br />

  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

You can then attach an event handler directly to the `submit` event of the `form` to send your AJAX request using jQuery's `$.ajax()` method:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission
  $.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); // the object returned from your Action will be displayed here.
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: And need to enclose button `Save` within `form` tag and change its type to `submit` .

Comment: @mmushtaq The OP edited that in as I answered. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: I've followed you, I've put a breakpoint at line ` e.preventDefault ();` But i do not see running into this line?
And of course I do not see running into the success function to get the data returned, but I see the returned data displayed in a new page.
I think because the post method of the form tag ???

Comment: I'm thinking I need to add `return false;` In some place

Comment: Help me, please